# Mobile version of Applications I need, to let App visible on Mobiles

Tags: android, ios, web, facebook-opengraph

I would like to know the Mobile version of the app I have in Facebook I need, in order to get that App visible on smartphones and tablets.

Should I build:
- Web app from scratch?
OR
- iOS/Android app from scratch?

Is Facebook helping you to build it?

I got sone information into DEvelopers section in Facebook, but it is not clear which version (web app or iOS app) would be better, and if they help you to build it (instead of integrating an existing one).

Please let me know!

Thanks a lot,
Giulia

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking at all. But one thing is for sure Facebook won't help you in any way to build an app :)

Comment: Giulia, you need to take the time to write your question properly if you want have people try to answer it. This is not just bad english, it's just you writing in hurry. Take a deep breath, relax, try again.

Comment: Actually, I couldn't understand what I have written! SO... I built an application in Facebook.com. I would like to let that application visible on smartphone also, but I do not know which kind of version I need. Web app could be enough? Or iOS/Android application that users have to download from App Store and Android market?

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you want your app to appear.

- To have an app inside a Facebook frame on the desktop located at an apps.facebook.com URL, you need to create a canvas app (a page you create that appears inside an iframe)
- To have an app that any smartphone user can view in their mobile web browser, you need a mobile web app
- To have an app that appears in the sidebar in the native iOS Facebook a app, you need a native iOS app.

To cover everyone you probably want some combination of all three. To make this easier, you can use PhoneGap to package up your mobile web site as a native app. PhoneGap basically gives you a framework for building native apps for iOS, Android, etc where the app content is just HTML/JavaScript hosted locally on the phone inside a standalone full-screen web browser.